# Ghost Recon Wildlands - stuck on "Money Truck" mission

Tags: steam, windows-10, ghost-recon-wildlands

I'm playing this game in single-player mode (not co-op or whatever), my 3 team mates are computer-controlled.

This mission requires you to hijack a money truck and deliver it to a compound patrolled by guards and then leave without being detected.

I can get the truck and deliver it to the compound without much trouble - but the last part - leaving undetected seems to be impossible for me.

Every time, one of my stupid computer-controlled teammates opens fire on the guards, or gets spotted somehow.  There is no apparent way to tell the teammates to "be stealthy".

Being seen will fail the mission, as will harming the guards apparently.

I've probably tried this mission 20 times and getting very frustrated with an otherwise highly enjoyable game.

Things I've tried so far:

1. Ordering my team into the corner of the compound and then ordering them to "hold position".  They sometimes just wander off anyway and get detected.
2. Using the Rebels "diversion" to distract the guards.
3. Shooting the guards.
4. Diversion grenades.  Still got caught because my team won't be stealthy.
5. Appealing for divine intervention.

For a special forces unit, these guys are real idiots and don't understand the rules of engagement for this mission.  There is no way I can see to prevent my team from joining me as soon as I exit the truck in the compound.  They are as stealthy as a brass band falling down the stairs.

How can I complete this horrible mission?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally cracked it!  The screenshot below is from the second half of the mission, after you have hijacked the truck and are driving towards the compound...

[image]

1. Approaching from the north-west corner of the picture, reverse the truck carefully down the steep slope at `A`.
2. Tell your stupid squadmates to stand BEHIND the truck and HOLD position.  You may have to yell it or draw them a diagram in crayon, because they are barely aware of what's happening.
3. Run back up to the main road and hide from the traffic behind the ruined buildings.  This gives you a stretch of cliffside from which you have good oversight down into the compound.
4. Use a silenced sniper rifle to headshot each of the 5 guards marked as `X` on the picture.  It's easiest to move east to west.  None of the guards' vision areas seem to include any other guards if you time it right.  All being well, your squad should tell you "all clear", which means you're almost done.
5. Check the mini-map for any enemy vehicles on the road, and when it's clear, run back to the truck and ignore your moronic colleagues.  Just don't even look at them, they are a disgrace to their uniforms.  Honestly, it's a shame you can't fire them or force them into early retirement, they are a menace.
6. Drive the truck to `B` (and drive very carefully, it's probably pretty badly damaged and can't take any collisions with anything at all!).
7. Slowly proceed through the automatic gate at `C` and around the building to the back of the compound at `Z`, and park up.  Once parked, DO NOT move the vehicle again!
8. Exit the truck and if you are paranoid, use the Rebel "Spotting" thing to scope out the compound near to you.  If that is clear, then you're good to run, carefree, to the entrance again at `C`.  Grab the nearby 4x4 truck, conveniently placed for your escape.
9. Drive back up to `B` and then onto the main road to freedom.
10. On the way back home, berate your team-mates for being useless at their jobs.  This part is optional, but feels like the right thing to do.